# How to use break last json while requesting for pagination through js

Tags: javascript, json, pagination, large-data

I have a large Json in which there are 400-500k urls. i want to create HTML using json in which 1000 URLs in each page. The problem is that we need to load whole json at that time can we somehow load only 1000 urls according to page number from json directly.

I know a simple solution is using database. i am just expecting solution with JSON file. i don't wanna use database.

Comment: have you tried any code?

Comment: no, i didn't, because i don't think we can break a single object json request in js request